# Sending data using AJAX and retrieve using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have the following ajax code:

```
optionScope.data().stage = 'b';
    $.ajax({
        url: "functions/contact.php",
        type: "post",
        data: {'stage': optionScope.data().stage},
        success: function(data, status) {
          console.log("data sent successfully");
          console.log(data);
          console.log(status);

      },
      error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
      }
    }); // end ajax call
```

How the data is being retrieved

```
<?php

      $stage = $_POST['stage'];
      echo $stage;

?>
```

Problem  is i do not see it being echo out. You may have notice that i've place a few log to keep track.
Well it does pass success, but for `console.log(data)`, it just prints `data` and not the actual 'stage' data.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

The php code is included in the main html page as such:

```
<?php include('functions/contact.php'); ?>
```

the php code is as follow:

```
<?php


  // Honey pot trap
  // Create a hidden input that is only visible to bots. If it's empty than proceed.
  if (empty($_POST['humancheck'])){
    // Proceeed if submit button have been pressed

      $fullName = $_POST['fname'];
      $email = $_POST['email'];

      $stage = $_POST['stage'];
      // Responses provided
      echo "<script>alert($stage); </script>";
      // Sanitize input data
[...]

?>
```

The JS file is included in the main page, and the php code is run once a user has hit on the submit button.

```
<form method="post" action="">
          <!-- Setting up the honey pot trap by including a hidden input only accessable by bots -->
          <input type="hidden" name="humancheck" placeholder="enter your title">
          <div class="input_container">

          <span class="input_icon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span><input class="inputContact" name="fname" type="text" placeholder="Your Name" required>
        </div>
          <br>

          <div class="input_container">
            <span class="input_icon">
              <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
            </span>
            <input class="inputContact" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" required>
          </div><br><br>

          <button type="button" class="previousfinal"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>&nbsp; Previous</button>
          &nbsp;
          <button class="final" name="mailSubmit" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-gift"></i>&nbsp; Get My Pack</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: did you try with another name 'data' in your succes function?

Comment: alert(data), try this what o/p do u got ?

Comment: thanks even when i change it to another name it doesn't make a difference, and i've tried to see if it was the value of the data that was wrong but even when i do stage: "hi" nothing get printed to console.

Comment: You should try looking at the Developer Tools and check the network tab.

Comment: thanks stage with its correct value is shown in the network tab with a status code of 200. However, i get an error when trying to echo it out using php unindefied stage index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was trying to figure out what `optionScope` might look like
and here is what I came up with:

```
var optionScope= new function() {
    return {
        data: function () {
            return {stage:'defaultValue'}
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't seem that you can assign a property of an object returned by a function in the way you are trying:

```
optionScope.data().stage = 'b';

console.log(optionScope.data().stage); // defaultValue
```

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6tojLe1y/)**

**Edit**

Ok, I think I understand where you're going wrong now.

Try this:

```
$(function () {                         // wait until dom is ready
    $('form').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();             // prevent form from submitting
        var data = $(this).serialize(); // get the form data
        data += '&stage=b';             // add stage to the data
        console.log(data)
        $.ajax({
            url: "functions/contact.php",
            type: "post",
            data: data,
            success: function (data, status) {
                console.log("data sent successfully");
                console.log(data);
                console.log(status);

            },
            error: function (xhr, desc, err) {
                console.log(xhr);
                console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks, i am able to send data succesfully, and they are shown in network tool with a status code of 200. i think the problem comes from organization. ive added a bit more context under my inntial post

Comment: you're still not showing enough info, there is no input named 'stage' in the form is the form being submitted by ajax somehow?  are you actually seeing "data sent successfully" in your console?

Comment: i think the problem could be that when the submit button is pressed the action="" refreshes the page and then the php code runs

Comment: Thanks andrew. were certainly heading in the right direction. how would my php code have to be adjusted because       echo "<script>alert($stage); </script>";
 in the php code doesnt run however, all of the data is succesfuly sent to the server with a 200 status code

Comment: so i guess the question, how would the php code run without refresh given that with ajax the data has been stored

Comment: to get the response to alert  you'd put in the success callback function: `alert(data)`

Answer (score 0):

change your code to this

```
optionScope.data().stage = 'b';
$.ajax({
    url: "functions/contact.php",
    type: "post",
    data: {stage: optionScope.data().stage}, // don't put quotes around stage
    success: function(data, status) {
      console.log("data sent successfully");
      console.log(data);
      console.log(status);

  },
  error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
    console.log(xhr);
    console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
  }
}); // end ajax call
```

you don't need to put quotes around the key for your data

Comment: He doesn't need to, but doing so doesn't change the outcome. quotes around object keys are optional.

Comment: I am not sure what else can cause the problem.  There is not enuf information.  If we only had acces to more of the code.

Comment: Agreed. which is why i refrained from posting an answer. There isn't enough information to form a good answer.

Comment: well i can say that there's nothing wrong with the ajax request as seen in network develeper tools the data is succesfully sent, the problem is why i cant use the post in php

Comment: i've added more context to the situation. you can find more info at the bottom of my post

Comment: i think the problem could be that when the submit button is pressed the action="" refreshes the page and then the php code runs